# Extjs 4 migration loading issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm migrating Extjs 2 to Extjs 4. To load mypage.html to some html id in the page. i'm using following code. In extjs 2 and 3 it works fine.But in Extjs 4 this url is executing with some GET values like mypage.html?_dc=1328433965894. So how to restrict the unnecessary passing parameters(_dc) in the urls.. Please help me..

```
var content_div = Ext.get(div_id);
content_div.load({
url:'mypage.html',params:{val1:'default'},scripts:true,text: 'Loading...'});
content_div.show();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dc parameter is a cache buster and should not have any impact on your request. If you really need to turn it off take a look at the docs for the element loader http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ElementLoader-cfg-ajaxOptions it basically says you can specify any config you typically put on an ajax request.  Thus if you set disableCaching option to false - you will remove that param.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your quick reply.This problem has resolved when i add disableCache:false property to load config.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct:  uptick my answer with an arrow above the Zero to the left of my answer. Then, click the hollow checkmark underneath that.